# Bootstrap 3.3.6 align right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Till now I was using Bootstrap 3.3.1, everything was fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/PKrUC/256/

Then I have to update Bootstrap to the latest version 3.3.6:

http://jsfiddle.net/PKrUC/257/

the buttons are on the wrong side. `align="right"` seems not working anymore.
I used the files from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6 as extern resources for the jsfiddle.
Anyone know why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did a little testing with http://jsbin.com/zaxeruseve/edit?html,output , the change happens when I switch bootstrap.min.css from 3.3.4 to 3.3.5(js file doesnt matter).  but I don't see any changes which would effect this https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v3.3.5 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'pull-right' in the individual button classes'

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/PKrUC/260/
```

Comment: ah ok, I only tried to `pull-right` the `btn-toolbar` but it didn't work. So I have to do that with every button, quite stupid... And I am still interested in what actually cause this behavior...

Comment: Well they probably changed something in the new version, its still a work in progress. Maybe check the release notes if you are really interested.

Comment: check my comment under the original post

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fix by adding `.text-right` in to parent element

Fix: http://jsfiddle.net/eycfyvx9/

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="packet_form">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <h4 class="pull-left">New Packet</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="panel_user">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="date">Expire-Date</label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input type="date" id="date" name="date" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="licence_text">Lizence:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="licence_text" name="licence_text" rows="20"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
              <a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:window.history.back()">Back</a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" formaction="add_packet.php">Save</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For this to work I have to get rid of the `btn-toolbar` as well. and it works only when I use HTML, but I have to `echo` the html-stuff sometimes, in this case there's no space between the buttons.